# Django restframework API as a backend for offline first mobile app

Tags: android, django, mobile, django-rest-framework, offline

I've just finished django app for multiple choice questions. However, I wanted to develop Ionic android app version of the web app. It's my first app and I am still learning web development. I'm not sure if Django RestFramework or firebase backend is more suitable for offline first app, particularly with respect to mostly text-based questions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you need to research the both options as there is a use case for each, but Django is not traditionally used for a mobile backend.

You need to weigh up the positive and negative of each and determine what suits your use case, at present you have not provided adequate information in order to make a determination either way.

Using Django as a backend is like saying you want to use WordPress as a backend, that is they are both content management systems that were not designed to serve as mobile backend Api's.

Additionally you need to consider the likelihood of your apps success, and what that means as a user count. If you feel that your app will be a success then don't waste your time with Django as you will very quickly have to spend money to scale the system.

The best option in general terms would be to use Firebase, a system specifically designed as mobile backend Api's.

However, to make an app like Uber, you’re going to require some custom server-side code. For example you’ll want real time updates of vehicle locations, availability, etc. This data can only be generated on the server since you’ll want multiple clients to access it at any given time. Firebase is probably too lightweight for this task, so making your own backend API would be a better option.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, the app could be a success and maximum users can't exceed half a million (as of now it's just practice for me). I have already done the logic to save user progress for each exam in Django and similar stuff. I guess I could reuse most of it if I decided to proceed with django restframework api. Implementing that in firebase as a backend is another task I have to learn how to do.

Comment: You can also, always use the firebase authentication for managing users and drf for rest of your complex computations OR connect your drf backend with firebase.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but is that for sake of taking advantage of firebase auth simplicity and security? Wouldn't that add comlexity?

Comment: No, it doesn't add to complexity. Firebase auth simply provides you with a token and a userid, which can be used as foreign key in your models in drf.

Comment: Also, Firebase has it's own login manager and state, which enables seamless signin and signout in your mobile app, especially if it is developed using react native.